# How to run a program and know its PID in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, pid

How to run a program and know its PID in Linux?

If I have several shells running each other, will they all have separate PIDs?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) to the rescue:

- `$!` is the PID of the last backgrounded process.
- `kill -0 $PID` checks whether `$PID` is still running. Only use this for processes started by the current process or its descendants, otherwise the PID could have been recycled.
- `wait` waits for all children to exit before continuing.

Actually, just read the link - It's all there (and more).

[`$$` is the PID of the current shell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PROCCID).

And yes, each shell will have its own PID (unless it's some homebrewed shell which doesn't `fork` to create a "new" shell).

Answer (score 3):

1) There is a variable for that, often `$$`:

```
edd@max:~$ echo $$                  # shell itself
20559
edd@max:~$ bash -c 'echo $$'        # new shell with different PID
19284
edd@max:~$ bash -c 'echo $$'        # dito
19382
edd@max:~$
```

2)  Yes they do, the OS / kernel does that for you.

Comment: How to use `$$` variable? Does it contain PID of last runned program or what?

Comment: Look at the example I gave. For the shell, it is its own PID.

Comment: in `bash` `$!` is the PID of the last background process.

Comment: @dldnh is this possible to receive the same in `sh`?

Comment: @Dirk but is it possible to know not the PID or the script, but the PID of the program runned by this script?

Comment: `sh` is often `bash` nowadays. `$ echo $SHELL` to see what you're running

Comment: @dldnh  $SHELL does NOT tell you what shell you are running.

Answer (score 0):

the top command in linux(Ubuntu) shows the memory usage of all running programs in linux with their pid. Kill pid can kill the process.